# How to insert data to custom table with Drupal 7 without coding?

Tags: views

I have a school assignment on Drupal 7, and I need some help.

I need to use the Views module to execute subqueries, or any other module you can suggest.

For example, I have a customer who has placed an order. On the order table there is a quantity and the product ID; on the product table there is a unit price.
I am able to use Global:Math Expression to multiple the quantity by the product ID. However, when I try and aggregate this sum to get the total price for the order, it does not work.

From what I can determine, this is because in my list of fields I include quantity, and unit price. (I can not do the math expression without them.) These are unique to each order; when I use aggregate, each row is separate (i.e. no total).

I know there is the View Calc module, by that only allows me to choose one order and find the total. I am trying to create a summary for every order a customer has made and the total prices.

Since I am not allowed to use code, this currently very difficult. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I think this is the first homework related post here.  Before any downvotes start, helping people with school assignments is not discouraged on SE.  I think this is the canonical thread on the topic, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: are you restricted from use special modules like drupal commerce?

Comment: Chuck, what is the actual assignment? If you're supposed to make an inventory system in Drupal, and populate it with data from an external database, that's not too hard.

Comment: I am assuming adding a comment here is the only way to answer you question... (I am new if you can't tell) Paul, I am creating a sort-of DBMS for a dummy database. I already have the tables on drupal. I want to allow users to add more data. (If the company gains a new customer, they can add new data).

Comment: It sounds like you have two databases.  Is this the case?  Or are you looking to manipulate the Drupal database?

Comment: When you first install drupal, I gave drupal access to a database. That is the database all of my tables are on. So, i think, yes I am trying manipulate the drupal database.

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, tell us what you have tried and what you expected and what happened.  Try the video series http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone to get some insight into the capabilities for views.

Comment: I have watched the entire series actually. Unfortunately, they webcast only works with content, not data tables. In the webcast, there was no need to explain how users can add more content. For data tables, this is less obvious.

Comment: still I think drupal commerce module will do what you want. http://drupal.org/project/commerce